# note-taking using natural handwriting in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

Hello how can we do the note-taking application using natural handwriting in iPad like the application WritePad for iPhone did?

How can we recognize the finger writing and how can we convert it into natural handwriting in the iPad,is there any public API's.

Any suggestions or any example code would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: There's no built-in API for handwriting recognition as far as I know.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your valuable time to share this Daniel Dickison.It saves lot of my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [source code](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/15846-simple-paint-app.html#post192098).. it's a paint app.. not exact what you looking but you can use the logic
post#13 Orange gold

Comment: Thank you very much Krian Thorat I will try to modify the code to get the natural handwriting effect.

Comment: I have seen some applications are allready implemented the note taking facility with natural handwriting effect. Could any one please suggest me in correct direction, I have been searching for it from long back but no luck.If you have any code or suggestions please help me. Thanks in advance.